# Why is Illustrator 10 moving my letters and outlines when I open a file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save, file-format, eps

I have a file that was originally created in CorelDrawX5 as both a dwg and pdf. I have opened both in Illustrator CS6 and they work fine.

I then saved it as an eps and ai for my supplier to work from, they have Illustrator 10 so I made sure it was compatible to work with ver 10.  However when my supplier opens it all the letters and outlines are split up and spread out. Attached is how it is opening and then how it should look.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

[image: How it is opening]

[image: How it should look]

Comment: Does this behavour happen with both files? ai and eps?
what happens when you open the ai? the eps?

What happens if you save as pdf?

Comment: It *might* be useful to show the same portion in it's intended form.

Comment: Apparently it happens with both eps and ai. I have attached an image of how it should look. Could it be something to do with grouping or paths perhaps? I don't use illustrator a great deal and am very much a novice.

Comment: I would try a combination of file format saves and exports form the eps/ai and pdf. Try a  lower illustrator format. Is the error occuring on your system?

Comment: Never seen that happen... Save as AI10 EPS... reopen in AI.. is it happening? If yes, you may need to copy/paste everything to a new file to completely remove some remnants of Corel/DWG code.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably a font embedding problem. Outline your text before saving as Illustrator 10. And try to save as different formats, like PDF or dwg, for your supplier to open in Illustrator 10.

If it is not a font problem, or you already outlined, try playing with Pathfinder to break up the grouping of the shapes, which should also help with rebuilding the CorelDraw code. Try Divide or Merge.